# Can Nginx do TCP load balance with SSL termination?

Tags: nginx, tcp, load

Due to some reason, I need to set up Nginx TCP load balance, but with SSL termination. I am not sure whether Nginx can do this. Since TCP is layer 4, SSL is layer 5, SSL pass-thru definitely work. But with SSL-termination?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Nginx can act as L3/4 balancer with stream module: https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/tcp-load-balancing/

Because SSL still tcp - Nginx can proxy SSL traffic without termination.

Also stream module can terminate SSL traffic, but it's optional.

Example 1: TCP tunnel for IMAP over SSL without SSL termination

```
stream {
    upstream stream_backend {
        server backend1.example.com:993;
        server backend2.example.com:993;
    }
    server {
        listen 993;
        proxy_pass stream_backend;
    }
}
```

In this case, SSL termination processed by backend1/2.

Example 2: TCP tunnel for IMAP with SSL termination.

```
stream {
    upstream stream_backend {
        server backend1.example.com:443;
        server backend2.example.com:443;
    }
    server {
        listen 993 ssl;
        proxy_pass stream_backend;
        ssl_certificate        /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/certs/server.key;
    }
}
```

In this case traffic between nginx and backend1/2 unencrypted (IMAP 443 port used).

Example 3: Receive unencrypted and encrypt it

```
stream {
    upstream stream_backend {
        server backend1.example.com:993;
        server backend2.example.com:993;
    }
    server {
        listen 443;
        proxy_pass stream_backend;
        proxy_ssl  on;
        proxy_ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/backend.crt;
        proxy_ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/backend.key;
    }
}
```

So, clients connect to our nginx without SSL and this traffic proxed to backend1/2 using SSL encryption.

Comment: I am not sure whether I can terminate SSL if I do tcp load balance. Do you have any link or info about it? thx

Comment: Well, if you are talking about balance HTTPS, you do not need tcp ssl termination on nginx. You can use tcp proxy (HTTPS traffic terminated by upstream). Or you can terminate HTTPS on nginx and you HTTP reverse proxy.

Comment: My concern is if I do layer 4 tcp load balance, can I terminate SSL on nginx level? Definitely I can terminate ssl by backend.

Comment: Up to you :) You can balance SSL traffic without termination. SSL traffic still tcp traffic, nginx with stream module act as tcp tunnel. In this case SSL will be terminated by backend.

Comment: But if you want to analyse unencrypted traffic, or, in HTTPS case, cache/rewrite some requests, you need to terminate SSL on nginx :) Ssl options in nginx's stream module useful if you want to get SSL traffic and talk with non-SSL backends. Or vise-versa, receive unencrypted traffic and encrypt it between nginx and backend.

Comment: I was amazed to see nginx terminate ssl even it do tcp load balance. The reason i say that is tcp is layer 4, ssl is layer 5. And I have googled a lot, and what I got is if I do tcp load balance, it is ssl pass-thru mode.

Comment: I edited answer and posted some examples for 3 cases :)

Comment: I have tried example 2, it showed " "ssl_certificate" directive is not allowed here ", not sure why? Have you tried ssl termination with tcp load balance?

Comment: I am guessing the ssl_certificate directive is not allowed to use under stream module...

Comment: Allowed but required stream_ssl_module (you need to compile nginx with --with-stream_ssl_module) http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_ssl_module.html

Comment: I have compiled nginx in local with --with-stream_ssl_module under mac, still shows not supported.. Not sure why, will give a try on linux.

Comment: The first 2 examples match my experiment result (using packet monitoring tool like Wireshark). However I don't know how the 3rd example leads to packet re-encryption, could you please explain how to inspect that ? thanks

Comment: @Ham From Wireshark's point of view traffic between client and nginx host should be visible and unencrypted and traffic between nginx and backend should be encrypted. May be you having problems because port 443 used in my example, try to change it to generic port for unencrypted traffic (example port 80 for HTTP traffic).

Comment: For anyone who needs to terminate SSL and then forward to an SSL upstream again, it seems that its not possible to do so in one server directive. You can however combine both example 2 and 3 by setting up a second server like example 3 that only listens on localhost (127.0.0.1:443) and forwards to your actual upstream and then have a server like example 2 forward to that localhost only server.