# how to transparently wrap tcp/ip request with ssl using windows api

Tags: security, winapi, ssl, driver, wfp

I'm developing a security system. It has a proxy server acting like a ssl termination using [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/nginx-tcp-ssl-termination/) which will forwards all tcp/ip connections from clients to other third-party systems.

The client-proxy connections must be authenticated and securely encrypted by ssl.

And my problems is:

Each client is a computer which installed Windows 7 OS or higher. It has been installed with some third-party applications which cannot be interfered. For the better user experience, all clients' tcp/ip outbound requests from any applications must be transparently "converted" into (or "wrapped" in) ssl requests before coming to proxy server. And my first idea is to develop a network driver to access these requests using windows api, namely WFP(Windows Filtering Platform). I have read its [online documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366510(v=vs.85).aspx) but it's  not easy to understand. Can you have to find some projects like this or tell me which sections in the documentation need to be focused? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/index.html)

Comment: @AndyBrown stunnel works like a port forwarding solution. This means that I have to change the ip address and port of the applications' servers. Some of them do not allow me to do this. So I still need a "real transparent" solution. Thanks :)

Comment: You could use (something like) stunnel in combination with a WFP callout driver that redirects outbound connections to the stunnel proxy.

Comment: Perhaps [ngrok + tunnel](https://ngrok.com/docs/secure-tunnels) might fit. Another option might be something like [tailscale](https://tailscale.com/kb/1151/what-is-tailscale/)

Comment: It's a bit unclear, so you are trying to add full encryption from the End User to Nginx and from Nginx to the App Service running on a separate host? (Currently, the connection to the App host is not encrypted; NGINX is an L3/L4 load balencer)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is a bit unclear but here are my thoughts:

You want to have full encryption between the End User Client to the App Service.

Current:

```
Client --(443: TLS)--> NGINX --(Clear; Port 80)--> App Service
                   (Terminate TLS)
```

---

Change:

```
Client --(443: TLS)--> NGINX --(TLS; Port 443)--> App Proxy -(Plain; 80)-> App Service
                   (Terminate TLS)             (Nginx with self-signed Cert)
```

The change is to add an additional Nginx server on the app server to provide the last layer of TLS between the load balancer and the App Service.

If your App service has the capability to serve SSL connections directly that's even better as you can just configure that in place of running an additional Nginx server on the app host. (If you wanted you could run apache or any other web server that supports proxy/load balancing capabilities)

If you are worried about the App Service port, it won't make a difference, the idea is that the `App Proxy` (being Nginx or the likes) will handle the encryption on a different port to then pass via localhost to the App Service (in plain text).

---

Additional Resources:

[Can Nginx do TCP load balance with SSL termination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39420613/can-nginx-do-tcp-load-balance-with-ssl-termination)

https://serverfault.com/questions/978922/nginx-proxy-pass-to-https

https://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2017/05/02/https-behind-proxy.html

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html