# Can I use a reverse proxy for direct database connection?

Tags: networking, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

Is it possible to setup a reverse proxy that would allow a database client to use a ssl port 443 connection and redirect to port 1521? I suspect it would not work. Can someone explain why or why not?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming Oracle database based on port 1521.

There is no problem setting up Nginx TCP (L4) proxy for any TCP backend. Look here https://www.nginx.com/blog/tcp-load-balancing-udp-load-balancing-nginx-tips-tricks/ for example configuration.

When it comes to terminating SSL (L5) and sending data decrypted to TCP backend it's also technically possible with `ngx_stream_ssl_module` but I have never tested it and from what I can read people have problems setting this up for postgresql:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_ssl_module.html

[Can nginx do TCP load balance with SSL termination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39420613/can-nginx-do-tcp-load-balance-with-ssl-termination)

I have never seen Nginx setup as proxy for databases. Instead connection poolers (i.e. pgbouncer for postgresql) are often used not only for pooling but also as SSL offloading service. They are in fact L7 proxies for databases.

Oracle equivalent for pgbouncer seems to be Oracle Connection Manager and it supports SSL so I'd strongly recommend using it instead of Nginx or any other general purpose reverse proxy server:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/netag/configuring-oracle-connection-manager.html#GUID-AF8A511E-9AE6-4F4D-8E58-F28BC53F64E4