# Options for proxying ldap connections to ldaps

Tags: proxy, ldap

I have a kubernetes cluster in which I would like to intercept outbound ldap connections, and wrap/re-initialize them as ldaps connections before reaching out to an external ldap server.  I've already done this for http to https calls with an nginx reverse proxy.  Is there something I can use to achieve the same for the ldap protocol?  I was initially looking at deploying an openLDAP server within the cluster that just acts as a proxy, but I have not found configurations to do what I'm looking for -- if it's indeed even possible with openLDAP.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`stunnel` can act as a generic TLS wrapper/unwrapper.

I think you could actually use Nginx for this, as its `stream {}` mode can proxy arbitrary TCP protocols (and looks like it should be able to [use TLS upstreams](http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_ssl_module.html)). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39421271/49849 for an example. Similarly, HAProxy is not limited to HTTP as far as I know.

OpenLDAP 2.5 comes with `lloadd` which acts as a dedicated LDAP proxy/load-balancer, which may be easier to configure than a passthrough slapd.