Multiple Listeners with Different ssl_options
Is it possible to define multiple listeners (e.g. for MQTT). Let's say:

listener 1 ::8883
listener 2 ::58883

And to set ssl_options.fail_if_no_peer_cert for:

listener 1 to true
listener 2 to false

Config:
[...]
ssl_options.fail_if_no_peer_cert = true
ssl_options.1.fail_if_no_peer_cert = false
mqtt.listeners.ssl.default = 8883
mqtt.listeners.ssl.1 = 58883
[...]

Reason: I want to have one port where TLS cert auth is required and the other where I allow user/pass authentication.

I think this it not possible with rabitmq. However, perhaps with a nginx/haproxy in front of rabitmq. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39421271/5781499 (i think you dont need the upstream part can directly pass your rabittmq as "proxy_pass" argument)

Yeah... that's what I thought... I still want to do TLS termination in RabbitMQ... the requirement allowing username/password authentication internal and only exposing the certificate authentication pot for external clients while doing TLS termination within RabbitMQ seems as of now impossible.

You can still do that. Enable TLS in your rabitmq installation, use nginx to forward on port 1:1 and the other port listen unecrypted but forward the traffic between nginx & rabitmq encrypted.
